# React native RecyclerListView and onViewableItemsChanged

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

i was using flatlist for my videos timeline app but i get some issues with it
so i decided to change flatlist by RecyclerListView
but RecyclerListView dont have onViewableItemsChanged
and the onVisibleIndicesChanged is not working right and so missy any idea about how to get the isViewable item like flatlist in RecyclerListView

```
<RecyclerListView
          style={{ flex: 1, height, width }}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          dataProvider={dataProvider}
          layoutProvider={layoutProvider}
          rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
          disableRecycling={true}
          initialRenderIndex={0}
          renderAheadOffset={height}
          scrollViewProps={{
            snapToInterval: height,
            snapToAlignment: "center",
            decelerationRate: "fast",
            disableIntervalMomentum: true,
            bounces: false,
            viewabilityConfig: {
              itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 100,
              minimumViewTime: 500,
              viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 100,
            },
            onViewableItemsChanged: () => console.log("Heyyyy"),
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecyclerListViw has prop onVisibleIndicesChanged. You can use that.

[image: sample image]

```
const onVisibleIndicesChanged = (all: number[], now: number[]) => {
        console.log(now)
};
```

It does not support viewabilityConfig as of Sept 2022. It is something in their To Do.